# Remove space around tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

How can I remove *ALL* space around TiKZ. So given MWE below, I want no space between fbox and the node box (so essentially I want to see 1 line). How to realize this?

Is this space in `tikzpicture` or in `\fbox`?

**How to remove space between `\fbox` and node**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.8cm and 0.2cm]%
    \node[draw] (center) {CENTER}; %
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`? But why are using `\fbox` when you can use TikZ already?

Comment: I am using it for 'debug' purpose. So I want to place multiple figures side-by-side in 1 column.

Comment: @robert, is any of received answer  solve your problem? if it, please accept (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) then this one, which do this on way you most liked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space is controlled equally to each of the four margins of the `\fbox` with `\fboxsep`, so the space is caused by `\fbox`. Setting it to `0pt` will remove the space at all.

Use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` inside a TeX group, i.e. `{...}` wrapping around will prevent that `\fboxsep` is changed globally.

Specifying `\node[draw]` has almost the same effect as using the outer `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.8cm and 0.2cm]%
    \node[draw] (center) {CENTER}; %
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
}

\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.8cm and 0.2cm]%
    \node[draw] (center) {CENTER}; %
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.8cm and 0.2cm]%
  \node[draw,line width=1.5\fboxrule] (center) {CENTER}; %
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\frame` instead of `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\frame{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.8cm and 0.2cm]%
    \node[draw] (center) {CENTER}; %
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: \frame instead of \fbox]

Comment: I always forget that there's a built-in command `\frame` ... (+1)